# Running multiple python unit test cases which are in different directories

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

I've written multiple unit tests using python unit test module in multiple directories
How to run all the tests from a single file

I have to integrate this file to a jenkins job and am using django

Answer (score 1):

Your folders will need to contain an `__init__.py` file in each of them, then you should be able to instantiate the unit test runner and pass it the parent directory, unit test discovery should pick up the sub-folders automatically.

Comment: The current directory and sub-directory contain __init__.py files. 
My folder structure and list of files are as below:
tests/test_file1.py
tests/a/test_file2.py
tests/b/test_file3.py

I've written the below code

`import unittest
import test_file1

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(test_file1)
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)`

If I'm adding any other file, test is getting failed. Could you please suggest